# I can not insert new row in table view

Tags: swift, uitableview

I have table view and I want to insert new row, when new data comes. I append new data to model, and after appending I want to update table view with new data

```
self!.messagesList.append(MessagesListResults(pk: pk, update_type: updateType, state: state, from_user: from_user, text: text, created: created))
let count = self!.messagesList.count - 1
let insertionIndexPath = IndexPath(row: count, section: 0)
ChatVC.tableView.insertRows(at: [insertionIndexPath], with: .automatic)
ChatVC.tableView.reloadData()
```

error is
***attempt to insert row 16 into section 0, but there are only 15 rows in section 0 after the update***

UPD: full code

**ChatVC**

```
    static var tableView: UITableView = {
        let tv = UITableView()
        tv.register(MessagesCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: MessagesCell.reuseIdentifier)
        tv.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0.976, green: 0.98, blue: 0.988, alpha: 1)
        tv.allowsSelection = false
        tv.separatorStyle = .none
        return tv
    }()
```

ChatVC extension for dataSource

```
extension ChatVC: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return messagesList.count
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: MessagesCell.reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! MessagesCell        
        let messages = messagesList[indexPath.row]
        let sorted = messagesList.sorted { (first, second) -> Bool in
            return first.pk < second.pk
        }
        cell.messagesLists = messages
        cell.messageLabel.text = sorted[indexPath.row].text
 
        return cell
    }
```

Here part of code of data parsing, data come from socket, I am using Starscream framework

```
         let data = Data(string.utf8)
                let json = (try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: [])) as? [String: Any]
                self.chatManager.getMessagesList { [weak self] (chat) in
                    self?.messagesList = chat
                    guard let chatData = json!["data"] as? [String: Any] else { return }
                    if let text = chatData["text"] as? String,
                        let state = chatData["state"] as? Int,
                        let from_user = chatData["from_user"] as? Int,
                        let pk = chatData["pk"] as? Int,
                        let updateType = chatData["update_type"] as? String,
                        let created = chatData["created"] as? String {
          
                       
                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            self!.messagesList.append(MessagesListResults(pk: pk, update_type: updateType, state: state, from_user: from_user, text: text, created: created))
                           ChatVC.tableView.reloadData()
                        }
```

Here chatManager

```
    var messagesList = [MessagesListResults]()
    var chatId = 0
    func getMessagesList(completionHandler: (@escaping ([MessagesListResults]) -> Void)) {
        let getAllMessagesURL = "http://192.168.100.70:8001/chat/with-managers/client/updates/?limit=200"
        let headers: HTTPHeaders = [
            "Authorization" : "FastToken 8af34fc7c2557517d8a3e747e497de6491a16350df6fa0af8afcbbe72035484efae69d46efa8a47feb75be3250d025b01f42b3b5ad723e5a32afc887c1f6879629b86655ce49e19cada8e289b38d79061160f538c6fa59388076396de1cd2886e2c2e8c5f706ad2bb79a23f034b889c835dd288e44c0cc257d048a22093e51226a60b198bf72aa40a11829771147b4d5"
        ]
        networkManager.getChatList { (ChatInstanceModel) in
            self.chatId = ChatInstanceModel.pk
            AF.request(getAllMessagesURL, method: .get, headers: headers).responseData { (responseData) in
                switch responseData.result {
                case .success(let data):
                    guard let messages = try? JSONDecoder().decode(MessagesList.self, from: data) else { return }
                    self.messagesList = messages.result
                    completionHandler(self.messagesList)
                case .failure(let error):
                    print(error)
                }
                
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: either remove the call to `reloadData` or `insertRows`

Comment: So remove the call to `reloadData` this will reload everything and no need to manually insert the row. Also make sure your row counts on the delegate is sourced from `messagesList`. Also the `self!` makes me think that you're doing this on a callback. First you should not use a `!` and make sure that you're on the main thread.

Comment: I am using `DispatchQueue.main.async{}` to be in main thread

Comment: What do you have in your `tableView(_:numberOfRowsInSection:)` method? you will need to reveal more of your code for help.

Comment: @Kubee `return messagesList.count`

Comment: I suggest you post your entire VC

Comment: @Kubee updated post

Comment: `self?.messagesList = chat` is being set for some reason and obviously not on the main thread. I would also look into using `Decodable` to decode your data.

Comment: @Kubee is data which came from api, I have two ways of updating data, first is from API, second is from Socket

Comment: Yes but `self?.messagesList = chat` is not done on the main thread. move `self?.messagesList = chat` to where you're syncing to the main thread just below `DispatchQueue.main.async {`

Comment: Maybe unrelated but sorting the data source array inside `cellForRow` is a pretty bad idea. And never call `reloadData` right after `insertRows`. It's redundant and you will lose the nice animation.

Comment: @Kubee I done how u said, but it is not working `DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            self?.messagesList = chat
                            self!.messagesList.append(MessagesListResults(pk: pk, update_type: updateType, state: state, from_user: from_user, text: text, created: created))
                             ChatVC.tableView.reloadData()
                        } `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to explicitly insert a `row` after updating the dataSource `messagesList`. Simply call `reloadData()`. It will automatically add a new `row` in the `tableView`.

Update your code to just,

```
self!.messagesList.append(MessagesListResults(pk: pk, update_type: updateType, state: state, from_user: from_user, text: text, created: created))
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    ChatVC.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: I did like you said, but table view row not updates

Comment: @MadiyarKupzhassarov Are you reloading the tableView on main thread?

Answer (score 0):

Check below code. This would work, because you are trying to load next indexpath. Actually you had only 15 after add. Add data after adding indexpath.

```
let count = self!.messagesList.count - 1
let insertionIndexPath = IndexPath(row: count, section: 0)
self!.messagesList.append(MessagesListResults(pk: pk, update_type: updateType, state: state, from_user: from_user, text: text, created: created))
ChatVC.tableView.insertRows(at: [insertionIndexPath], with: .automatic)
ChatVC.tableView.reloadData()
```

Comment: Same error, but now attempt to insert row 18 into section 0, but there are only 18 rows in section 0 after the update

Comment: Actually problem is ChatVC instance. You have to update datasource for VC. You are only updating to self i.e current view controller

Comment: You are getting data in different view controller and updating UI in ChatVC. So Update array list value in ChatVC. Then problem will be solved.  That means definitely you will have array in ChatVC. Update the recent array or the item on it.

Comment: Thanks, I did it, it is because of mine inattention. But Insert method not needed